# working with exchange in .net 4

Tags: .net-4.0, exchange-server

We moved to .net 4 and the work with exchange doesnt work anymore.
I'm using interop.cdo dll and when doing sessionclass I'm getting an exception -
retrieving the com class factory for component with CLSID faile due to the following error: class not registered.

Is there a way to fix this with this dll or should I replace all the work with exchange?
If I do - what is the best way? I cant seem to find information about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please check if the output platform match the COM platform (force to x86 bits in most cases)

Comment: It matches, any other idea?